# SPFx gulp trust-dev-cert Error

Tags: spfx, error, nodejs, gulp

I am getting following error after running 'gulp trust-dev' in SPFx:

```
PS C:\Users\s.framework\Code\ZEN> gulp trust-dev-cert
Build target: DEBUG
[15:11:11] Using gulpfile ~\Code\ZEN\gulpfile.js
[15:11:11] Starting 'trust-dev-cert'...
[15:11:11] Starting gulp
[15:11:11] Starting subtask 'trust-cert'...
[15:11:11] [trust-cert] Attempting to trust a development certificate. This self-signed certificate only points to localhost and will be stored in your local user profile to be used by other instances of 
debug-certificate-manager. If you do not consent to trust this certificate, click "NO" in the dialog.
[15:11:11] Error - 'trust-cert' sub task errored after 291 ms 
The executable file was not found: "certutil"
[15:11:11] 'trust-dev-cert' errored after 296 ms
```

Please help.

Comment: From the error it looks like you are missing executable file for "certutil", Can you verify if file exists for "CertUtil" can be found on the System32 directory (C:\Windows\System32\certutil.exe). Possible bug: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/316

Comment: File is there. In the directory you pointed out. As a side note, my regular user on the box in not the one I am running VS Code with. I wonder if that is why the machine cannot communicate with itself. However, again - I am attempting to build SPFx environment with an account that is admin on the box.

Comment: Also please notice that there are more then one certutil files on hte machine